# Porblema al subir imagen al servidor con Spring java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee, maven

ya llevo 2 dias sin poder solucionar esto y no veo de otra que recurrir aqui, el problema es qeu intento subir la imagen a servidor con el framework spring de java y colocar la ruta de su ubicacion en la base de datos, pero al mandarla me arroja un error y realmente no se que pueda ser aqui les dejo el metodo que hace lo subida

```
public static final String TEACHER_UPLOADED_FOLDER = "images/teachers/";

//CREATE{img}
@RequestMapping(value = "/teachers/images", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-type=multipart/form-data"))
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> uploadTeacherImage(@RequestParam("idTeacher") Long idTeacher, @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile multipartFile, UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder) {
    if (idTeacher == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Please set id_teacher"), HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    if (multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Please select a file to upload"), HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    Teacher teacher = _teacherService.findById(idTeacher);
    if (teacher == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(new CustomErrorType("Teacher with id_teacher: " + idTeacher + " not found"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    if (!teacher.getAvatar().isEmpty() || teacher.getAvatar() != null) {
        String fileName = teacher.getAvatar();
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        File f = path.toFile();
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }
    }

    try {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateName = dateFormat.format(date);

        String fileName = String.valueOf(idTeacher)
                + "-pictureTaecher-" + dateName + "."
                + multipartFile.getContentType().split("/")[1];
        teacher.setAvatar(TEACHER_UPLOADED_FOLDER + fileName);

        byte[] image = multipartFile.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(TEACHER_UPLOADED_FOLDER + fileName);
        Files.write(path, image);//****AQUI ME ARROJA EL ERROR****

        _teacherService.update(teacher);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG).body(image);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity(
                new CustomErrorType("Error during upload: " + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()),
                HttpStatus.CONFLICT
        );
    }
}
```

> Me arroja el error en esta parte del codigo:

```
byte[] image = multipartFile.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(TEACHER_UPLOADED_FOLDER + fileName);
        Files.write(path, image);//****AQUI ME ARROJA EL ERROR****
```

> Aqui esta el objeto teacher:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idTeacher;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "avatar")
private String avatar;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Course> courses;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_teacher")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<TeacherSocialMedia> teacherSocialMedia;

public Teacher () { }

public Teacher (String name, String avatar) {
    this.name = name;
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public Long getIdTeacher () {
    return idTeacher;
}

public void setIdTeacher (Long idTeacher) {
    this.idTeacher = idTeacher;
}

public String getName () {
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAvatar () {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar (String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public Set<Course> getCourses () {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses (Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

public Set<TeacherSocialMedia> getTeacherSocialMedia () {
    return teacherSocialMedia;
}

public void setTeacherSocialMedia (Set<TeacherSocialMedia> teacherSocialMedia) {
    this.teacherSocialMedia = teacherSocialMedia;
}
```

}

> El error que me arroja es el siguiente:
>   La linea 197 de TeacherController esta dentro del metodo que esta
>   arriba

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: images/teachers/2-pictureTaecher-2018-09-27.png
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:215)
at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:218)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.write(Files.java:3355)
at com.platzi.profesoresplatzi.controller.TeacherController.uploadTeacherImage(TeacherController.java:197)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: Puedes ser más especifico por favor y poner la línea con la excepción que te lanza.

Comment: @DarthVader hola, mira ahi esta. es la primera linea: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: images/teachers/2-pictureTaecher-2018-09-27.png`

Comment: Creo que me expliqué mal, la línea de código.

Comment: Listo @DarthVader

Comment: Primero asegurate que la ruta como tal exista y que tengas permisos de escritura sobre **images/teachers/**.Aquí estoy viendo que es relativa, ¿Por que no se la pones absoluta? Windows, por ejemplo: **C:\\images\\teachers\\2-pictureTaecher-2018-09-27.png** o unix **/images/teachers/2-pictureTaecher-2018-09-27.png**.

Comment: uso unix y ya me asegure de eso, Intente colocar la ruta absoluta y funciona, pero no se por que la relativa no funciona

Comment: Si es un war que deployas en el servidor, cuando haces eso buscará la ruta **relativa** a donde se encuentra la **clase**(es decir en el war), de tal manera que tendrá que ser absoluta, por **ejemplo**: **/export/home/images/teachers/**, para que vaya y busque en el servidor y no dentro del war.